# Clarity on responsive design pixel width

Tags: css, responsive-design

New to responsive design and I'm trying to work something out.

The Galaxy Note 2 has a pixel dimension of 1280 x 720 and I specify the following CSS:

```
@media (min-width:769px){
     #mobile{
         display:none;
     }
     #tablet{
         display:none;
     }
     #desktop{
         width:100px;
         float:left;
         background-color:green;
     }
 }
 @media (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px){
     #desktop{
         display:none;
     }
     #tablet{
         width:100px;
         float:left;
         background-color:black;
         color:white;
     }
     #mobile{
         display:none;
     }
 }

 @media (max-width:320px){
     #desktop{
         display:none;
     }
     #mobile{
         width:100px;
         float:left;
         background-color:blue;
         color:white;
     }
     #tablet{
         display:none;
     }
 }
```

The phone (as expected) shows the mobile "version" of the site but I don't understand why it falls into the <321px category when it has the dimension previously mentioned!

The following code does this?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Hope for some help with this!
Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've disabled zooming (maximum-scale, user-scalable)?  Users typically do not like this...

Comment: I don't really understand that line of code, I've just read about it. I saw that online and was asking what the code does more than anything! I'm trying to grasp what (in general) is viewed as moving from mobile to tablet to desktop!

Comment: Of interest: http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/, http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/, http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: I'll be sure to have a read. Instantly, I see the first article is about content specific design, not device first. What I'm trying to understand mainly from this question is how the screen pixels of a tablet or phone breakdown to be much less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because css uses "device independent pixels" which aren't the same as device pixels. You could also use media queries on the pixel ratio to select devices with a higher density of pixels.

[A List Apart: A Pixel Identity Crisis](http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis)

Additionally, please note that the actual resolution is not lower. The browser is just using a different unit of measurement.

Comment: That article is EXACTLY what I was after. I understand the need to develop the responsive design based on content etc but couldn't understand how it scales down when hardware pixels were different. Really appreciate that!

Comment: Nearly 6 years late but I'll echo that sentiment. None of the articles I read elaborated beyond calling them "CSS pixels", including Mozilla. A really good article by A List Apart.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers on some mobile devices use a lower resolution to speed up the renderer. You can use JS to check what width and height the browser is using.

```
alert('Window: '+$(document).width()+'x'+$(document).height());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fGVAg/

Comment: I see, that's interesting. Is there any pattern to how these sizes change? Are they known as viewports then?